# Translate animation code

Tags: android, translate-animation

I am a noob coming from a PHP background so kindly excuse me if this is too basic a question.

Basically, this is what I want to do:
make an image animate/drop from the top of the screen to 25% down in 5 seconds

so I googled and ended up on:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

the problem is I cannot find any sample code there (like in php you can type a function, eg: php.net/explode and it shows you an example with explode(), but here for a noob like me it's extremely difficult.) is there anywhere to get the code to do the above (or a starting point to which i can modify to achieve the above)?

Comment: Here is a tutorial for a similar thing:
[slide up /down translate ](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/slide-up-down-translate.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample code is available via the SDK and AVD manager.  You should download API Demos.  It shows you how to do this two ways.  Number 1 via XML and 2 via code.  The class is called LayoutAnimation2.java.  You can also view it right online via the Android Developer Website, look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LayoutAnimation2.html).

Comment: Hey!Thanks for replying! I have the SDK at: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Android/android-sdk/docs/sdk/android-3.0.html and I am able to search as well, but there is no sample code to be found there, I am confused as to how to use this local copy of the SDK to learn. That layoutanimation.java is good, and I have been checking out the demo files, but these demo files dont cover everything :( is there a step by step thingy to learn this?

Comment: Including actual source in answers is more helpful, not only link to external pages.