# Split a single screen into two parts + animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

As according to my project requirement, I want to split the screen into two parts like:
[image]

I know this thing is available in version 3.0 but I am working on 2.3 so I have to do it manually..

And I want to split the screen as 25% of ListView and 75% of content view..and a single button at the top of the screen..

Now whenever used select a option from listView then automatically the split part slide left and the whole screen will be shown as a content screen only....Now the ListView screen is not visible to the user..

And whenever the user click on the button at the top of the screen..Only then the listview part is shown to user as shown in the above image..

Here what I am thinking is I will take two different layouts and on 1 layout I will display the ListView and on another I will list the content view..But how can I show here the animation of slide left and right whenever user select an option or click the button .

If anyone has some better option,then pls let me know..

**[EDIT]: Also I want to show on these screens ????**

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to apply animation on those 2 base views with the help of TranslateAnimation class in android.
please refer the following links for more details:
[Translate animation code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293991/translate-animation-code)
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Animation3.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LayoutAnimation2.html